Formula proof of similarity transformation in robotics
I'm really new to linear algebra. So, this might be quite trivial to ask. But I have trouble understanding this formula. The text describes a relation of a linear transformation in different basis. Denote $A$ as some linear transformation in $x_0y_0z_0$ and $B$ is the same transformation but in basis $x_1y_1z_1$. Then, their relation is
$$B = (R^{0}_{1})^{-1}AR^{0}_{1}$$
, where we have the basis change matrix from $x_1y_1z_1$ to $x_0y_0z_0$
$$R^{0}_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \cdot x_0 & y_1 \cdot x_0 & z_1 \cdot x_0  \\
x_1 \cdot y_0 & y_1 \cdot y_0 & z_1 \cdot y_0 \\
x_1 \cdot z_0 & y_1 \cdot z_0 & z_1 \cdot z_0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Why is this?

Try the representation: $$R_0^1=\begin{bmatrix} x_0^T\y_0^T\z_0^T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & z_1\end{bmatrix}$$
